# Chrome not detecting file type with File API

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, fileapi

I am trying to get file type validation working with https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload but it isn't working.

Looking at some console output, it appears that the file type is empty.

Chrome 43 and IE 11 seem to be broken, whereas Firefox 37 is fine.

Upload form code: (the `<form>` isnt needed, looking at examples, its used here mainly for presentation)

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="" method="post" data-url="<?php echo $upload_url; ?>">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2">Files</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                       <span>Select files...</span>
                                       <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="userfile" multiple />
                                    </span>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <p><small>NB. Max file size is 2mb. <br />Allowed file types are .jpg/.jpeg, .png, .gif and .bmp.</small></p>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

File Upload code:

```
$(function () {

        'use strict';

        var url = $('.form').data('url'); // this is a Google Cloud Storage Upload URL.

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|bmp|png|svg)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 2 * 1048 * 1048,
            add: function (e, data) {
                $('#files').empty(); // clear file list to show newly added/uploaded files
                $('#errors').empty(); // clear errors
                data.submit();
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                console.log(data);

                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    if(data.result[index].error) {
                        $('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"/>').html('<strong>Warning!</strong> '+data.result[index].error).appendTo('#errors');
                    } else {
                        $('<p/>').html('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="' + data.result[index].url + '" data-filename="'+data.result[index].filename+'" data-src="'+data.result[index].src+'" data-url="'+data.result[index].url+'"/></div><div class="col-sm-8"><p><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> ' + data.result[index].filename + ' successfully uploaded!</p><p>Click the thumbnail to add it to the canvas.</p></div></div><hr />').appendTo('#files');
                    }
                });
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('.progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
                if (progress == 100){
                    $('#success-message').addClass('well');
                    $('#success-message').html('<h4>Would you like to upload another file or view library?</h4><a href="<?php echo site_url('gallery/upload'); ?>" class="btn btn-success fileinput-button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Yes, add more images</a> <a class="btn btn-success" href="<?php echo site_url('gallery/'.$previous_type.'/'.$previous_category); ?>"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> No, go back</a>');
                }
            },
            fail: function(e, data) {
                console.log(e, data);
            }
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
            .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');

    });
```

Comment: Could provide a code segment and a working example where we can reproduce the issue you are facing?

Comment: Just trying to get an example sorted. In the meantime, I noticed some weird stuff going on with the official demo - https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html - I was able to upload JPGs that are over the 999kb file size limit.